# Fused conv implementation does not support grouped convolutions for now

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am using the FERN 2013 dataset from kaggle for the emojify project. The dataset consists of **48X48 grayscale** images.
When I go to train the model, I get an error as shown below

UnimplementedError:  Fused conv implementation does not support grouped convolutions for now.
[[node sequential_3/conv2d_6/Relu (defined at :1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_3421]

Function call stack:
train_function

My code is as follows :

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('train/', batch_size=32, class_mode='categorical')

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True)
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('test/', batch_size=32, class_mode='categorical')


cnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(48, 48, 1)))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(48, 48, 1)))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
cnn.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

cnn.fit(x=training_set, validation_data=test_set, epochs=25)
```

Comment: Please, share your codes in a code format.

Comment: Generally, you can see above issue due to the difference in the number of channels in the image and the model. Ensure they are the same. But here i can see you had mentioned `1` because of gray scale.  If you can share me reproducible code to replicate above issue, i will try to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. I found the error. My `input_data'shape` is different than the `input_shape`. My `input_shape` is three-dimensional but my `input_data'shape` is one-dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

After this, the error might in the train_datagen.flow_from_directory ,this function has a param--target_size, if you don't to set up maybe the output is (256, 256) (mean the size of image), and this is different with you input_shape.I don't know is this right or not, you can try. If this is helpful to you, that's great!